# Creating table and populating within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

My goal is to create a stored procedure that creates a new table and inserts the data from a long Select statement into said table. Seems fairly straightforward but I am getting an error at the END statement and cannot understand why.

Essentially the code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTProc 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO NEW_TABLE 
    FROM (long select query)
END
```

However there seems to be an error right at the END:

> Incorrect syntax near 'END'. Expecting AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID.

Is what I'm trying to do legal in a SQL Server stored procedure? As the select statement in the middle that populates works fine on its own, I thought maybe the method I was using to try and populate the newly created table is not the best way to do this?

Any advice or a way I can restructure this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Why not create the table outside the stored proc and just have the stored proc insert the data?

Comment: What are you going to do when you want to execute this procedure a second time? Using select into this will fail. And of course the error is because of something in the code that you removed during your post.

Comment: If you would post the entire query, that would be helpful for others to help you.

Comment: `FROM (long select query)` when you do a subquery like this in ANY `SELECT` statement you have to give subquery an `Alias` which is why it's complaining about expecting an `AS`. Try: `FROM (long select query) as subqry` and see if it'll run.

Comment: I was avoiding creating the table manually beforehand as I was planning on just having the stored proc create it automatically.  question is, can you select into a table like that using a query, or do you have to use another method?

Comment: JNevill - genius!  thanks very much, that is exactly what I needed.  appreciate the help!

Comment: Once the table is created you can't create it again, but you can INSERT into it. I'm guessing that's actually what you want to do, CREATE the table once outside the procedure, then in the procedure perform `INSERT INTO <tablename> SELECT foo, bar FROM <some other table>;`

Comment: yes this will be a one time run and then I will truncate / refill the table thereafter

Comment: What is the lifespan of the table you want to create? Does it only live during the execution of the procedure? If not, do you want it to stay forever there?

Comment: You should be using a temp table here instead of persistent table.